# Visual Studio @using statements get altered

Tags: visual-studio, using-directives

I have a VS issue, VS2022 but it also happened in the previous version.  In fact its been happening for a few years.

When I do certain operations, often moving files within VS, I find I get a load of syntax errors on build.  Several razor pages, not even ones I was editing or had open have their using statements changed from:

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using System.Text
@using System.Text.Encodings.Web
```

to

```
@    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@    using System.Text
@    using System.Text.Encodings.Web
```

I then have to go into each file & remove the spaces.  It happens fairly often.  I've reported it to MS but they can't reproduce.
Anybody experienced this?  Anybody got a fix?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/6830

Comment: Yep that's pretty similar.  The wait goes on.